# Selfhosted agents do not receive the values of environment variables

Tags: linux, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I set the environment variable "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0" in my linux environment because I need to set this variable in a Selfhosted agent. When the agent is created and the installation is done (sudo ./svc.sh install username), the variable appears in the list of System capabilities but when starting the agent as a service (which is my need because it needs to run constantly) with the command sudo ./svc.sh start username, the agent is started but the variable disappears from System Capabilites.

I ask for help to solve this problem and understand where I am going wrong in the settings.  Agent Version Used: 2.220.5

I tried to do the following:

- Run the agent with the command: ./runsvc.sh username
- I tried to stop and start the service again
- Tried to reinstall the agent without success.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my problem adding the variable 'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED' in the file env.sh in the field "varCheckList=".

Like this:

varCheckList=(
'LANG'
'JAVA_HOME'
'ANT_HOME'
'M2_HOME'
'ANDROID_HOME'
'GRADLE_HOME'
'NVM_BIN'
'NVM_PATH'
'VSTS_HTTP_PROXY'
'VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME'
'VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD'
'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
'AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY'
'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'
)